# Updatepanel inside usercontrol ascx file not updating gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to be slick and I'm putting this user control in a div that covers the whole page.
However when I click on the search button I get a full postback.
Any ideas on how to get it to not postback and just update the gridview?

And just to be clear. The following control is in a ascx file. Which is called in a aspx page.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PropertyViewAddEntity.ascx.cs"
Inherits="UserControls_PropertyViewAddEntity" %>

<p>Search for State City County zip</p>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2ae">
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1ae" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2ae" runat="server" Text="Search"  CausesValidation="false" />
            </p>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2ae" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3ae"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2ae_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="zipcodeid" HeaderText="zipcodeid" SortExpression="zipcodeid" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="zip_code" HeaderText="zip_code" SortExpression="zip_code" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="state" HeaderText="state" SortExpression="state" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="city_alias_name" HeaderText="city_alias_name" SortExpression="city_alias_name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="county_name" HeaderText="county_name" SortExpression="county_name" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2ae" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

btw the control is in a placeholder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ControlContainer" runat="server"/>
```

and called from the code behind.

```
Control mycontrol = LoadControl("~/UserControls/PropertyViewAddEntity.ascx");

    ControlContainer.Controls.Add(mycontrol);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have finally figured out the issue.**

In order for things to work properly adding the user control via codebehind will not work!

To get things working properly you must declare the usercontrol on the page so that you can access the UpdateMode="Conditional" property of the usercontrol.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="my" TagName="AddEntity" Src="~/UserControls/PropertyViewAddEntity.ascx"  %>
<my:AddEntity Visible="false" ID="test1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Inherit" UpdateMode="Conditional" />
```

I set the Visible property of the control to false so that I can show it via button click.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And in the code behind I did this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    test1.Visible = true;
}
```

Once the updatemode is set. Everything works as it should.

Comment: What a hero solution. Crazy that it also doens't come up in the Intellisense menu for the UserControl tag.